Use Overlay Volume Mounts with Podman Compose
I am trying to mount a directory to my docker, but have any writes be scoped to within the container. I believe this should be possible with the Overlay Volume Mount option documented at: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#volume-v-source-volume-host-dir-container-dir-options
Reproduction compose file:
services:
  app:
    image: docker.io/library/httpd
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app:O  # :O Parameter for overlay volume mount
    working_dir: /app
    command: touch out.txt


However writes are still being propagated to the host file system instead of to the containers overlay filesystem.
Container inspect output:
{
  "Id": "1fc65d9f6ee1750216a7fc953fd5ab1190a1d7d7da1cf11b0df6645b673dc767",
  "Created": "2024-05-27T02:32:40.888883068Z",
  "Path": "httpd-foreground",
  "Args": [
    "httpd-foreground"
  ],
  "State": {
    "Status": "running",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 576406,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
    "StartedAt": "2024-05-27T02:32:41.203398049Z",
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "Image": "sha256:356125da059505ee31a72f8a27fe5703c84886832b08ea565fa4a5ec4bfb722c",
  "ResolvConfPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/1fc65d9f6ee1750216a7fc953fd5ab1190a1d7d7da1cf11b0df6645b673dc767/userdata/resolv.conf",
  "HostnamePath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/1fc65d9f6ee1750216a7fc953fd5ab1190a1d7d7da1cf11b0df6645b673dc767/userdata/hostname",
  "HostsPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/1fc65d9f6ee1750216a7fc953fd5ab1190a1d7d7da1cf11b0df6645b673dc767/userdata/hosts",
  "LogPath": "",
  "Name": "/poc-app-1",
  "RestartCount": 0,
  "Driver": "overlay",
  "Platform": "linux",
  "MountLabel": "",
  "ProcessLabel": "",
  "AppArmorProfile": "",
  "ExecIDs": [],
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
      "/mnt/c/Users/RedRidingHood/Downloads/poc/app:/app:rw,rprivate,rbind"
    ],
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "LogConfig": {
      "Type": "journald",
      "Config": null
    },
    "NetworkMode": "bridge",
    "PortBindings": {
      "80/tcp": [
        {
          "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
          "HostPort": "8080"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RestartPolicy": {
      "Name": "",
      "MaximumRetryCount": 0
    },
    "AutoRemove": false,
    "VolumeDriver": "",
    "VolumesFrom": null,
    "ConsoleSize": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "CapAdd": [],
    "CapDrop": [],
    "CgroupnsMode": "",
    "Dns": [],
    "DnsOptions": [],
    "DnsSearch": [],
    "ExtraHosts": [],
    "GroupAdd": [],
    "IpcMode": "shareable",
    "Cgroup": "",
    "Links": null,
    "OomScoreAdj": 0,
    "PidMode": "private",
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
    "SecurityOpt": [],
    "UTSMode": "private",
    "UsernsMode": "",
    "ShmSize": 65536000,
    "Runtime": "oci",
    "Isolation": "",
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Memory": 0,
    "NanoCpus": 0,
    "CgroupParent": "",
    "BlkioWeight": 0,
    "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
    "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
    "CpuPeriod": 0,
    "CpuQuota": 0,
    "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
    "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
    "CpusetCpus": "",
    "CpusetMems": "",
    "Devices": [],
    "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
    "DeviceRequests": null,
    "MemoryReservation": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "MemorySwappiness": 0,
    "OomKillDisable": false,
    "PidsLimit": 2048,
    "Ulimits": [
      {
        "Name": "RLIMIT_NPROC",
        "Hard": 4194304,
        "Soft": 4194304
      }
    ],
    "CpuCount": 0,
    "CpuPercent": 0,
    "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
    "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
    "MaskedPaths": null,
    "ReadonlyPaths": null
  },
  "GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
      "LowerDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a7d0e2a5c00427b1316753f23eff2b74de2bfe0322bf0a8e07c92a7c7dca0b4e/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/5e8d8ba961097b7dc2cf24bd8fd3c6ff015966f5cbe40671f2c12364bef36a05/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a8301c7ce94a308b3adeb70892e3d27f4aa97c60dbe9987ef1ac80647e4713a5/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/dd30c510fd540d1128564621bdac0bf99e68107baa7c64aa3d2a9cfa2355f31a/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/3e71e9263a05d8842b80c3ad262d4ad9f2054b2538e93627cca8db8c884cc8ee/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/5d4427064ecc46e3c2add169e9b5eafc7ed2be7861081ec925938ab628ac0e25/diff",
      "MergedDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/66f023b6f680c8e685de14d20c116cdbb07902ee051f0d1ab9864ca9215bfefd/merged",
      "UpperDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/66f023b6f680c8e685de14d20c116cdbb07902ee051f0d1ab9864ca9215bfefd/diff",
      "WorkDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/66f023b6f680c8e685de14d20c116cdbb07902ee051f0d1ab9864ca9215bfefd/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay"
  },
  "SizeRootFs": 0,
  "Mounts": [
    {
      "Type": "bind",
      "Source": "/mnt/c/Users/RedRidingHood/Downloads/poc/app",
      "Destination": "/app",
      "Mode": "",
      "RW": true,
      "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
  ],
  "Config": {
    "Hostname": "1fc65d9f6ee1",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "ExposedPorts": {
      "80/tcp": {}
    },
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "HTTPD_SHA256=ec51501ec480284ff52f637258135d333230a7d229c3afa6f6c2f9040e321323",
      "HTTPD_PATCHES=",
      "PATH=/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "container=podman",
      "HTTPD_PREFIX=/usr/local/apache2",
      "HTTPD_VERSION=2.4.59",
      "HOME=/root",
      "HOSTNAME=1fc65d9f6ee1"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "httpd-foreground"
    ],
    "Image": "docker.io/library/httpd:latest",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/apache2",
    "Entrypoint": [],
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {
      "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "03c941ac6f6ed66aa739526e15d23890a264786edf55b28c31c7660510137d84",
      "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
      "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
      "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:356125da059505ee31a72f8a27fe5703c84886832b08ea565fa4a5ec4bfb722c",
      "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
      "com.docker.compose.project": "poc",
      "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "C:\\Users\\RedRidingHood\\Downloads\\poc\\docker-compose.yml",
      "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "C:\\Users\\RedRidingHood\\Downloads\\poc",
      "com.docker.compose.replace": "f68f017863f92d0c3b416747aaae15d64f06988bdd61b44856352bb2e34af239",
      "com.docker.compose.service": "app",
      "com.docker.compose.version": "2.24.0"
    },
    "StopSignal": "28",
    "StopTimeout": 10
  },
  "NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "",
    "SandboxKey": "/run/netns/netns-5802d61f-699b-5ece-1991-5b4b8f0e4208",
    "Ports": {
      "80/tcp": [
        {
          "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
          "HostPort": "8080"
        }
      ]
    },
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
      "poc_default": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
          "poc-app-1",
          "app",
          "1fc65d9f6ee1"
        ],
        "MacAddress": "3a:65:fd:67:79:0b",
        "NetworkID": "poc_default",
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "10.89.1.1",
        "IPAddress": "10.89.1.33",
        "IPPrefixLen": 24,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "DriverOpts": null,
        "DNSNames": null
      }
    }
  }
}


podman info
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.35.3
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpuset
  - cpu
  - cpuacct
  - blkio
  - memory
  - devices
  - freezer
  - net_cls
  - perf_event
  - net_prio
  - hugetlb
  - pids
  - rdma
  - misc
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.10-1.fc40.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.10, commit: '
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 99.89
    systemPercent: 0.06
    userPercent: 0.04
  cpus: 20
  databaseBackend: sqlite
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: container
    version: "40"
  eventLogger: journald
  freeLocks: 2044
  hostname: redridinghood
  idMappings:
    gidmap: null
    uidmap: null
  kernel: 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 13683953664
  memTotal: 16599429120
  networkBackend: netavark
  networkBackendInfo:
    backend: netavark
    dns:
      package: aardvark-dns-1.10.0-1.fc40.x86_64
      path: /usr/libexec/podman/aardvark-dns
      version: aardvark-dns 1.10.0
    package: netavark-1.10.3-3.fc40.x86_64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/netavark
    version: netavark 1.10.3
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.14.4-1.fc40.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 1.14.4
      commit: a220ca661ce078f2c37b38c92e66cf66c012d9c1
      rundir: /run/crun
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +LIBKRUN +WASM:wasmedge +YAJL
  os: linux
  pasta:
    executable: /usr/bin/pasta
    package: passt-0^20240510.g7288448-1.fc40.x86_64
    version: |
      pasta 0^20240510.g7288448-1.fc40.x86_64
      Copyright Red Hat
      GNU General Public License, version 2 or later
        <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
      This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
      There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: false
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: ""
    package: ""
    version: ""
  swapFree: 4294967296
  swapTotal: 4294967296
  uptime: 70h 44m 25.00s (Approximately 2.92 days)
  variant: ""
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /usr/share/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 3
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 3
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.imagestore: /usr/lib/containers/storage
    overlay.mountopt: nodev,metacopy=on
  graphRoot: /var/lib/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 1081101176832
  graphRootUsed: 1656594432
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Supports shifting: "false"
    Supports volatile: "true"
    Using metacopy: "true"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 7
  runRoot: /run/containers/storage
  transientStore: false
  volumePath: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 5.0.2
  Built: 1713312000
  BuiltTime: Wed Apr 17 10:00:00 2024
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.22.1
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 5.0.2

